# .NET Windows 7 Jumplist - Checkbox / Radio Jumplist Item

Tags: .net, windows-7, jump-list

I would like to create a jumplist item that functions with a tick or round checkmark in front of the option.  I am using the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) for the .NET implementation.

I have had a look around the SDK documentation but I couldn't find anything that would enable a tick or round checkmark in front of the Jump List Item.  I understand that I could just hack the icon in front of the Jumplist item, however is that the best method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using an icon hack is really the only way to accomplish what you are trying to do. For the frequent/MRU lists, you won't even have icons as a option.

You can defined the icons for items that are considered custom Tasks. When clicked, it will pass a command line argument to your application, and you will need to read and stored that information. When you rebuild the jumplist, you would populate the jumplist and set the icons according the the most recently stored state.

I think this is certainly a feature that should have been provided for the Windows 7 release, but it isn't quite as big of a problem as the fact that you cannot disable the Task links in a jumplist...

Comment: Thanks! I might just do an icon hack then.  I hadn't even tried disabling a task link. Seems like quite a few things were not thought of with the new taskbar and jumplists. i.e. certain keywords within executables and shortcuts can't be pinned.